# My phalaenopsis orchids are dying while others are healthy

Tags: orchids

Since last September I have bought many orchids. Now it is hot and dry weather in Ranchi, India where I live. While my cattelya, dendrobium, vanda, catasetum and other orchids are healthy and developing new growths, the phalaenopsis orchids are dying. First the buds are drying and falling off, then the spikes and some leaves turn yellow and fall, and then the rest of the leaves and the stem dies.

The phalaenopsis are potted in moss. I water the orchids every 2 days. There is no root rot in the phalaenopsis orchids. But still they are dying. Please help.

Thanks.[image: This was a very healthy plant with flowers last week]